# CLLocationManager not start on iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager, simulator

All the sudden, the CLLocationManager won't start on the simulator - I observed this by finding out that the gps icon does show up on the status bar, and also no callbacks to the didUpdateToLocation delegate. What could be the reason causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Add one GPX file in Xcode and in it specify Latitude and Longitude...:)

for example wpt lat="23.04472" lon="72.56839"

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your simulator to version below 5.0? Because simulator version below 5.0 won't support Location Services. Also in simulator in settings make sure Location Services are enabled.